# Requests ImportError in SublimeText 3

Tags: python, sublimetext3

Tell me please, how to upload correctly `python` library `requests` to `ST3`? Through `pip3` (`macOS`), it is installed correctly. When I write `show` or `check` in `Terminal` it tells that everything is ok.

```
$ pip3 check requests
No broken requirements found.
```

So when I try to run code (`Sublime-REPL` is installed) the error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 4, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

Also I have `PyCharm` on mac, so in `PyCharm` everything works correctly, without any troubles.

Comment: What version of Python is the REPL running? If it's just running `python` it's probably running version 2 and not version 3, so it can't see the libraries that are installed.

Comment: Create a test script in ST3 and type `python --version` to see whether it's using 2 or 3

Comment: Actually yes, the trouble was in 2nd version in REPL. I've changed field 'cmd' in main.sublime-menu and everything works. Many thanks, guys!